# Is there a powerful database system for time series data?

Tags: database, performance, time-series

In multiple projects we have to store, aggregate, evaluate simple measurement values. One row typcially consists of a time stamp, a value and some attributes to the value. In some applications we would like to store 1000 values per second and more. These values must not only be inserted but also deleted at the same rate, since the lifetime of a value is restricted to a year or so (in different aggregation steps, we do not store 1000/s for the whole year).

Until now, we have developped different solutions. One based on Firebird, one on Oracle and one on some self-made storage mechanism. But none of these are very satisfying solutions.

Both RDBMS solutions cannot handle the desired data flow. Besides that, the applications that deliver the values (e.g. device drivers) cannot be easily attached to databases, the insert statements are cumbersome. And finally, while having an SQL interface to the data is strongly desired, typical evaluations are hard to formulate in SQL and slow in the execution. E.g. find the maximum value with time stamp per 15 minutes for all measurements during the last month.

The self-made solution can handle the insertion rate and has a client-friendly API to do it, but it has nothing like a query language and cannot be used by other applications via some standard interface e.g. for reporting.

The best solution in my dreams would be a database system that:

- has an API for very fast insertion
- is able to remove/truncate the values in the same speed
- provides a standard SQL interface with specific support for typical time series data

Do you know some database that comes near those requirements or would you approach the problem in a different way?

Comment: For fast and convenient (in-memory) processing you could try [`pandas`](http://pandas.sourceforge.net/), for fast IO -- [`PyTables`](http://www.pytables.org/moin).

Comment: Also you could try Starcounter. It can handle a few million SQL requests per second on a single Windows Server 2008. It is still in closed beta, but it has been running in production on very large installations for some time now. An email should suffice to get a copy.

Comment: i have a similar, if not identical question that was closed as off-topic as well, so i moved it here: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/18302/database-for-large-volume-of-metrics-key-value-timestamp

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Most other answers seem to mention SQL based databases. NoSQL based databases are far superior at this kind of thing.

Some Open source time-series databases:

- https://prometheus.io - Monitoring system and time series database
- http://influxdb.com/ - time series database with no external dependencies (only basic server is open-source)
- http://square.github.io/cube/ - Written ontop of [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/)
- http://opentsdb.net/ - Written on top of [Apache HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/)
- https://github.com/kairosdb/kairosdb - A rewrite of OpenTSDB that also enables using [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) instead of Hadoop
- http://www.gocircuit.org/vena.html - A tutorial on writing a substitute of OpenTSDB using Go-circuits
- https://github.com/rackerlabs/blueflood - Based on [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/)
- https://github.com/druid-io/druid - Column oriented &  hadoop based [distributed data store](http://druid.io/)

Cloud-based:

- https://www.tempoiq.com

Comment: Have you looked at column-oriented databases?

Comment: Wikipedia offers an overview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_series_database#Example_TSDB_Systems

Comment: Erol offers a complete list: http://www.erol.si/2015/01/the-complete-list-of-all-timeseries-databases-for-your-iot-project/

Comment: Since OpenTSDB is on the list, I would mention Axibase Time-Series Database as it supports opentsdb protocol and tcollector itself as of May 2015: http://axibase.com/products/axibase-time-series-database/writing-data/tcollector/

Comment: That's a great list.  Throwing Blueflood (cassandra base) into the mix:  https://github.com/rackerlabs/blueflood

Comment: ElasticSearch is scalable, open source, and can be used as a TSDB. CERN did an analysis and decided it to be the winner for them ( http://cds.cern.ch/record/2011172/files/LHCb-TALK-2015-060.pdf )

Comment: Take a look also at [VictoriaMetrics](https://github.com/VictoriaMetrics/VictoriaMetrics) time series database - it provides high performance at low resource usage.

Answer (score 8):

influxdb :: An open-source distributed time series database with no external dependencies.

- http://influxdb.org/

Comment: It's not distributed unless you pay $$$ ( https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.0/high_availability/clusters/ )

Answer (score 2):

Consider IBM [Informix](http://www.informix.com/) Dynamic Server with the [TimeSeries](http://www.ibm.com/software/data/informix/blades/timeseries/) DataBlade.

That is, however, an extreme data rate that you are working with.  (Not quite up to sub-atomic physics at CERN, but headed in that general direction.)

---

*Fair disclosure*: I work for IBM on the Informix DBMS, though not on the TimeSeries DataBlade per se.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server [StreamInsight](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/solutions-technologies/business-intelligence/complex-event-processing.aspx)

[Microsoft StreamInsight BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee362541.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the hint. StreamInsight sounds interesting and have to investigate it. Best of all, after what I understand, it is included in SQL Server? My concern: Storage is still in SQL Server. Will it be able to handle the requested data flow? StreamInsight docs say it can handle up to 100000 events/s "in peak time" but that must refer to some kind of buffering. What is the steady state rate?

Comment: storage speeds depend on your hardware; spend enough and you can get 17.2GBytes per second!!  1.2GB a second is attainable with a good 12 - 18 drive RAID array

Answer (score 1):

You can try HDF5 for time series data. It is extremely fast for such applications.

Comment: HDF5 seems to be a storage format. Could you elaborate a bit more on the usage in the context of time series data?

Comment: A python library based on HDF5 is availble at https://github.com/afiedler/tstables

Answer (score 0):

As Jonathan Leffler said, you should try Informix Timeseries feature. It is included in all editions of Informix at no additional charge. You can take a look at the TimeSeries functions it supports:

[IBM Informix Time series SQL routines](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/idshelp/v117/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.tms.doc/ids_tms_135.htm)

You can access the data through sql functions or virtual view interfaces, you can even insert into the view.