# Time-series databases with horizontal scaling for metric monitoring?

Tags: cassandra, time-series, database-performance, influxdb

I'm researching about time-series databases for metrics monitoring that scale horizontally easily.

I read about [Prometheus comparison with other databases](http://prometheus.io/docs/introduction/comparison/) (as of 2014). It seems that uses less space that the rest of the options, but it does not scale horizontally. [This](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8368509) is relevant also, but is from 2014 and I would like to hear about new databases also.

Could anyone compare time-series database alternatives?

*I'm aware of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816429/is-there-a-powerful-database-system-for-time-series-data) but is from 2014 and new alternatives should be taken into account in this question*

Answer (score 3):

[InfluxDB](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v0.10/introduction/getting_started/) is a single Go binary with no external dependencies that supports clustering for horizontal scaling of storage and throughput. A single node c4.8xlarge machine can process over 500k points per second, and with appropriate schemas it is possible to persist over 1 million values per second on a much smaller box (c4.2xlarge). Customers are managing over 500GB in a single node, although recent storage engine improvements have driven the size on disk down to ~10% of prior requirements. InfluxDB only requires 2-3 bytes per numeric metric recorded.

In addition, InfluxDB is a member of the TICK stack, a unified time-series platform for the collection, storage, management, altering, and visualization of time-series metrics for the IoT, devops, and real-time monitoring use cases. Each member of the TICK stack supports multiple protocols and data sources/sinks, but when combined together the ease of use and simplicity of operation are very compelling.

I run support for InfluxData, the company behind the OSS projects.

Comment: I read in the Prometheus link that I posted before that InfluxDB as of 2014 used to use a lot of memory; it's nice to see that that was fixed.

Answer (score 1):

**If** you're looking at a solution to store metrics with high scalability, it may worth looking at **cyanite** = a plugin for graphite to store data on **Cassandra**: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=htp-HiT5I1Q,

Github repo: https://github.com/brutasse/graphite-cyanite

Answer (score 1):

[Axibase Time Series Database](https://axibase.com/docs/atsd/) can be scaled up by adding storage nodes to the cluster without the need to shard and index data manually.

ATSD stores data quite efficiently too: 4+ bytes per time:value tuple, depending on regularity and value data type/variance.

Disclosure: I work for company developing ATSD.